How to lookup item value and sort by header name and value from small to largest
I am stuck at this problem. Been looking everywhere in Google using several phrases but no luck (or maybe I am just super confused at the moment).
I am looking for an excel formula where it can sort the value of an item and also return the name of the item's belongs to. The data as per shown below.

Does excel formula support this type of functions?
~ without using macros and/or special coding in macro
Thank you
Hopefully anyone can help on how to solve this problem

As per screenshot, use the following formulas.
I4 cell =SORT(B4:E4,,,TRUE)
and
M4 cell =TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,FILTER($B$3:$E$3,FILTER($B$4:$E$8,$A$4:$A$8=$H4)=I4))

